# Refactoring code to respect OOP principles

Tags: java, class, oop, design-patterns

This is an interview question. They give you code and they ask you to criticize it and to rearrange it in a more OOP manner.

```
public abstract class Storage{
    public static Vector<IStorage> objects = /*...*/; // Create a vector IStorage empty, I do not know how

    public Storage(String xmlFile){
        ReadFromXMLFile(xmlFile);
        objects.addElement((IStorage)this);
    }
    protected abstract ReadFromXMLFile(String xmlFile); 

}

public interface IStorage{
    public String getAuthor();
    public String getEditor();
    public String getName();
    public boolean isBook();
    public boolean isFood();
}

// Exemple d'implémentation 
public class Novel implements IStorage extends Storage{
    private String author;
    private String editor;
    private String name;
    private boolean historical;

    public Novel(String xmlFile){
        super(xmlFile);
    }

    public String getAuthor(){return author;}
    public String getEditor(){return editor;}
    public String getName(){return name;}

    public boolean isHistorical(){return historical;}
    public void setHistorical(boolean b){historical = b;}

    public void setAuthor(String a){author = a;}
    public void setEditor(String e){editor = e;}
    public void setName(String n){name = n;}

    public boolean isBook(){return true;}
    public boolean isFood(){return false;}

    public boolean needRefrigeration(){return false;}

    private ReadFromXMLFile(String xmlFile){
        // Loads the object from an XML file
// The implementation of this method is not given
    }
}
```

I couldn't detect bad OOP programming? what is wrong in this code and how can we change it?

Thanks.

Comment: There is so much wrong I'm going to have to close it as too broad. I could talk for 5 minutes straight on the problems.

Comment: I suspect that one of the issues that you're supposed to identify is the use of a common abstract class for both food and novels, which in any reasonable kind of system would be completely unrelated.  After all, do you really want to be getting the author or the editor for a piece of food?  The static vector is also a bit of a problem.

Comment: @Bohemian - if that were not the case, it wouldn't be a good interview question.

Comment: @DavidWallace and yet it is that bad. It's a refactoring fest.

Comment: @Bohemian - Please tell me the most serious problems in the design. saying that the question is too boad won't help. thanks

Comment: In brief, fields should be private with accessors, there should be two classes Book and Food, only morons use Vector, Storage should probably implement IStorage, then there's software patterns that can be applied. You could probably write a small thesis

Comment: Don't you think we should split the interface into two (one for book one for food)?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Novel implements IStorage extends Storage
```

That is where the problem is.....

Comment: I don't think the idea of the question is to pick out the syntax errors in the code.  OP has described this as being about respecting OOP principles, not about obeying Java's syntax rules.

Comment: no problem with the static Vector in the abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this code won't even compile.

Novel extends Storage, and since it's not abstract, it must implement `ReadFromXMLFile`, but since it implements it as a private method, the `Storage` constructor can't call it.

Beside that, the constructor of `Storage` assumes that any sub-class of Storage would implement `IStorage`, since it casts `this` to `IStorage`.

```
objects.addElement((IStorage)this);
```

Therefore, `Storage` must implement `IStorage`.

Comment: what the difference if it is implemented a private or not? the problem is that the superclass is created before the subclass, so even if it is implemented as public, it will stay a problem.